# XSLT template match on attribute and use this attribute as node name

Tags: xml, attributes, xslt-2.0

We receive XML's from a customer which contains the ID of the product is an attribute in the node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <product Q="23">
        <id>27</id>
        <id_name>Product1</id_name>
        <description>Vegetables</description>
    </product>
    <product Q="38">
        <id>39</id>
        <id_name>Product2</id_name>
        <description>Dairy</description>
    </product>
    <product Q="59">
        <id>37</id>
        <id_name>Product3</id_name>
        <description>Bread</description>
    </product>
</root>
```

What I want to do is use this attribute as a node name.
The output would be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
    <Q23>
        <id>27</id>
        <id_name>Product1</id_name>
        <description>Vegetables</description>
    </Q23>
    <Q38>
        <id>39</id>
        <id_name>Product2</id_name>
        <description>Dairy</description>
    </Q38>
    <Q59>
        <id>37</id>
        <id_name>Product3</id_name>
        <description>Bread</description>
    </Q59>
</root>
```

I can get the get the XSL to select the correct node and attribute but it's not producing the desired output at the moment.

```
<xsl:template match="finishing/@Q[.='23']">
<Q23>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../../id,  ../../id_name, ../../description,*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
</Q23>
</xsl:template>
```

Output:

```
<product>
       <Q23 Q="23"/>
          <id>27</id>
          <id_name>Product1</id_name>
          <description>Vegetables</description>
    </product>
```

I'm sure it should be relatively simple to accomplish but not sure if using template match is the right way to go.

Comment: IMHO, it is a bad design to have dynamic XML element names: `<Q23>`, `<Q38>`, etc.

Comment: I agree with @YitzhakKhabinsky. The reason is that most XML development tools are optimised for the case where element and attribute names are types, and their values are instances. XML doesn't care about the semantics of your names, but many of the processing tools do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily match on `product` and create the new element with `<xsl:element name="Q{@Q}"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:element>` e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="product">
  <xsl:element name="Q{@Q}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

and have the other copying handled by the identity template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This customer has a fixed set of products (the Qn value), around 15 total. To make sorting later on in the process easier we figured having a dedicated node for each product is prefereable.